# What is the correct way to work with GraphQL Custom Input types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I'm new to GraphQL, and working on trying to implement an args class to be used as a custom input type.

Here is an example of my class:

```js
@ArgsType()
export class CreateVariableArgs {
    ... other properties

    @Field(type => String, { nullable: true })
    customClass?: customClassInputType[];
}
```

And here is my input type:

```
@ArgsType()
export class customClassInputType {
    @Field(type => String)
    name: string;

    @Field(type => Boolean)
    isDefault: boolean;

    ... other properties
}
```

What I want to be able to do, is pass along an array of my custom Entity from a React Typescript UI. My query is a mutation request to my GraphQL server. I want to do some work in the resolvers, and eventually save the data in a PostGres db, and return the data or throw errors to the UI.

Currently my graphQL server doesn't know what the custom input type is. There must be a way that GraphQL can handle more than just primitive scalar types, but I haven't been able to find any documentation, and have been banging on this for a week with no success. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the error that I am getting in my debug console.

```sh
{"message":"Cannot determine GraphQL input type for customClass","level":"error"}
{"message":"Error: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for customClass\n    at Function.getGraphQLInputType (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:415:19)\n    at argumentType.fields.forEach.field (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:361:28)\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at Function.mapArgFields (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:357:29)\n    at params.reduce (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:350:22)\n    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)\n    at Function.generateHandlerArgs (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:332:23)\n    at handlers.reduce (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:285:28)\n    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)\n    at Function.generateHandlerFields (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:278:25)","level":"error"}
```

Is it possible to work with custom types? Or am I limited to stringifying my array of custom types and working with them in that form?

Answer (score 3):

You should change customClassInputType

```
@InputType()
export class customClassInputType {
    @Field(type => String)
    name: string;

    @Field(type => Boolean)
    isDefault: boolean;

    ... other properties
}
```

and use customClassInputType like following

```
@ArgsType()
export class CreateVariableArgs {
    ... other properties

    @Field(() => customClassInputType, {nullable:true})
    customClass?: customClassInputType[];
}
```

because @InputType will generate real GraphQLInputType and should be used when you want to have nested object in args

and @ArgsType is virtual and it will be flattened in schema:

more detail can be found here
https://typegraphql.ml/docs/0.17.0/faq.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and get back to you when I have a chance to work on this part again. What I ended up doing is stringifying an array of these types, and then parsing it in the resolver. Not ideal, but works for now.

Comment: actually, I think that should be `@Field(() => [customClassInputType], ...)` where the type is put between square brackets to define it as an array.

Answer (score -2):

Obviously you can work with custom types.
but I don't know how to make it work in typescript

I am using `graphql` libraries in javascript, it's provide `GraphQLObjectType` for Query and `GraphQLInputObjectType` for Mutation which allow you to make a new type of your own

```
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } from 'graphql'

export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserType',
  fields: () => ({
    username: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: () => 'name',
    },
  }),
})
```

Sorry, can't help too much

Comment: Try to look at this [graphql-typescript](https://pusher.com/tutorials/graphql-typescript)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did try to use that library at first, however I was not able to get it to work with Typescript.